# I am stuck in this number system equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the least number which when multiplied by 7 gives all 9 in the answer, how to solve this equation?

Answer (score 4):

You can just do long division.  Divide $7$ into a series of $9$'s adding more $9$'s until you get a remainder of $0$.

Alternately, you are asking $10^n-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$, so make powers of $3$ until you find one with the correct remainder because $10 \equiv 3 \pmod 7$.